# Having trouble coding recurring notifications for Android?

Tags: android, notifications, push

I would like to send my users a notification message every 12 hours, but am having trouble figuring out where to start.  Can somebody please provide a step by step guide to adding a simple notification to my users?  Thanks in  advance

Comment: @KenWhite Moved the link to comment. Click [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks/) for the tutorial.

Comment: Is your question about sending notifications, or about scheduling recurring events? The subject seems to indicate it has to do with recurring events, but the text seems to indicate it has to do with sending notifications. Can you [edit] to clarify what it is you're asking? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Steps are:

- Setup an Alarm via [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
- On BroadcastReceiver of alarm fire populate a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) you can then setup the next alarm in 12h

Another way is to create from the beginning recurring every 12h.

see this example [AlarmManager and Notification in Android](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.gr/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
private static final int TIME = 1000*60*60*12;

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                showNotification();
            }
        }, 0, TIME);//start immediatly, run every 12hours


    public void showNotification() {
        final NotificationManager mNotification = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        final Intent launchNotifiactionIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityLauchedOnClickNotif.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    REQUEST_CODE, launchNotifiactionIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(titleString)
            .setContentText(messageString)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        mNotification.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
```

this code works since API 11 ! (notification.builder)